# how to echo variables into js objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to make a Question and answer with choices on a webpage which would retrieve question data from the database.
The var for the js object looks like this:

```js
    var questions = [{
        question: "What is 2*5?",
        choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
        correctAnswer: 2
    },...
```

Although I can make these have a fixed number of questions only, I would like to make it more dynamic.

This is what I have currently written:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var questions = [
            <?php
            include "functions/connect.php";
            $selqq="select * from quiz_question where QUIZ_ID=2";
            $runqq=mysqli_query($con,$selqq);
            while($rowqq=$runqq->fetch_array())
            {    
                echo "{ question: '".$rowqq['QUESTION']."',
                choices: [".$rowqq['CHOICE0'].",".$rowqq['CHOICE1'].",".$rowqq['CHOICE2'].",".$rowqq['CHOICE3']."],
                correctAnswer: ".$rowqq['ANSWER']."},";
            }
            ?>];
</script>
```

This does not work for me, maybe because of that "," near the end, and placing it at the beginning will do the same.
How do I make it so that I can place as many objects as I want in an array? is it possible?

Comment: [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your script code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var questions =
        <?php
         $data = null;
         $i = 0;
        include "functions/connect.php";
        $selqq="select * from quiz_question where QUIZ_ID=2";
        $runqq=mysqli_query($con,$selqq);
        while($rowqq=$runqq->fetch_array())
        {    
            $data[$i]['question']  = $rowqq['QUESTION'];
            $data[$i]['choices']  = $rowqq['CHOICE0'].$rowqq['CHOICE1'].$rowqq['CHOICE2'].$rowqq['CHOICE3'];
            $data[$i]['correctAnswer'] = $rowqq['ANSWER'];
          $i++;
        }
         echo json_encode($data);
        ?>
   </script>
```